Why was my question "Can Rabbinic Judaism be proven false apart from any reference to Christianity?" deleted?
Why was my question "Can Rabbinic Judaism be proven false apart from any reference to Christianity?" deleted?  Christianity is a religion that claims to be the fulfillment of a different religion that still exists (sort of).  This is a strange claim that requires evidence to back it up because otherwise people will say we are just lying.  Most of the apologetics in this area tends to be rather stupid and fideistic, perhaps because people are afraid of offending Rabbinists.  My answer to this question contained valuable information that is hard to find that I wish I had had available to me from the beginning.  I know it doesn't explicitly refer to Christianity, but Christianity does claim to be the true Judaism so I think it is appropriate to discuss the false Judaism and how we know which is which.

'Apart from any reference to Christianity' causes the question to comprehensively exclude itself from a website called 'Christianity'.
Demonstrating that God's activity in Israel was a precursor to the New Testament requires reference to the New Testament in order prove the point.
Isolating the Old from the New, is not a valid means of demonstrating that the New came from the Old.
The question makes stipulations that prevent itself from being answered.
If Rabbinic Judaism has faults within itself, that have no bearing on the New Testament, then that is a matter for Rabbinic Judaism to consider for itself.
That would not concern a website called 'Christianity'.
